# oozie error while launching pig job

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to launch a pig job from oozie and it fails .

Oozie stacktrace :

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1897)
        at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:430)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1803)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1895)

Answer (score 1):

It unable to find `PigManin` class. Include following entry in job.properties.

```
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
```

Comment: Or set oozie.libpath property to the (HDFS) folder in which the pig jar can be found.